# Getting "vector subscript out of range" error

Tags: c++, vector, variadic-templates

I'm currently trying to get "variadic functions" down and just trying to load 4 names in a string vector and then print them out.  When I do this with 'int' type and use numbers, it works fine, but when I use a string vector I get the error.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdarg>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;



int count;

vector<string> namesVector;

void names(int count, ...)
{
    va_list namesList;

    int i; // for loop

    va_start(namesList, count);

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        string currentElement;
        currentElement = va_arg(namesList, string);

        namesVector[i] = currentElement;

    }

    va_end(namesList);
}


int main()
{
    int nameCount = 4;

    names(nameCount,"jon", "maggie", "joan", "alfred");

    for (int i = 0; i < nameCount; i++)
    {
        cout << "Name at element " << i << " is: " << namesVector[i] << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: I suggest you spend some time [reading up on how `std::vector` works](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 3):

C++ only allows to use trivially-copyable types as variadic arguments. As `std::string` is constructible from a `char*` pointer which points to a null-terminated buffer, you may use `char*` instead of `std::string` type. Just replace

```
currentElement = va_arg(namesList, string);
```

with

```
currentElement = va_arg(namesList, char*);
```

in your code. To get rid of this limitation, consider [variadic templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template), which generate code in compile-time for any type you use.

Your code also contains a run-time error. This:

```
namesVector[i] = currentElement;
```

is very likely to crash your program as you didn't allocate any memory in the vector. Vectors are actually dynamic arrays, so you should either pass a size argument to appropriate constructor, or call `resize` on the vector. In you case you may do neither of it, but just use `push_back method`:

```
namesVector.push_back(currentElement);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That fixed it and thanks for explaining!